# Changing the default settings for a console application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++-6

I would prefer that a console app would default to

multithreaded debug.
warning level 4.
build browse information.
no resource folder.

Does anyone know of any technique that would allow me to create a console app, with my desired options, without manually setting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. What you want is to create your own project template. You can then select that template from the New Project wizard. I wasn't able to location documentation on how to create a project template in Visual Studio 6, but [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247120(VS.80).aspx) explains the procedure for Visual Studio 2005. Hopefully you will find those instructions to sufficiently similar.

Comment: What you describe is not available in msvc 6

Answer (score 0):

I have concluded this is impossible.

The is support for custom appwizards for windows projects, but not console projectcs.

This is where I did research.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/genwiz.aspx?fid=15478&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3& 
sort=Position&view=Quick&select=1266895

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950410.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300499(VS.60).aspx

The custom appwizard will accept windows projects as a base for the template, but not console projects.   A message dialog appears that claims that the base project selected is not a c++ project.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be fairly easy to do.

Create a new console project in your workspace, name it 0_console

Set its characteristics the way you want them to be. (warning level 4 ...)

get out of msvc, and use windows explorer to copy the project directory.

paste it in at the same directory level as the 0_console project.

rename it to be what ever you want the new project to be.

go into that directory, and edit the dsp file, and replace the 0_console values 
by the new name.

save that, and go into msvc, and simply insert the project into the work space